# Date validation dd-mm-yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: php, regex

I get dates from a text area in the dd-mm-yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy format (the user is allowed to use - or /) How do I check (using a regex or php) if the date is valid? Is there a regex or php method done this far to validate dates in this format? I tried searching here but could not find anything.

Comment: I found this. It'll take - / as well as .

$

ver_date('29-02-2009');

function ver_date($c_date)
 {
  if(preg_match('/^(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])[\s\.\-\/](0[13578]|1[02])[\s\.\-\/]((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)[\s\.\-\/](0[13456789]|1[012])[\s\.\-\/]((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])[\s\.\-\/]02[\s\.\-\/]((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|(29[\s\.\-\/]02[\s\.\-\/]((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$/', $c_date))
  {
   echo "Date OK";

  }  else
  {echo 'Date Error';}
 }
$

Comment: Getting dates from user text input is just asking for endless trouble. Use drop-down selection boxes or something similar.

Comment: @GZipp: even if he take the date from drop-down - he have to validate it

Comment: @zerkms - Well, that's my point. Validating a date that is in a known standard format is trivial (and if the input form is designed correctly it will be valid from the get-go). Validating a date entered free-form is no better than a guessing game.

Comment: @zerkms - Let's say you have a page for potential customers to specify dates of delivery of your product. One of them doesn't read instructions very well (and there will be more than one) and wants delivery on the fourth of March, 2011. He enters, either accidentally or in his usual way, "03/04/2011". Your "validator" sees that as the third of April. On the fifth of March the customer angrily contacts you because he hasn't received the product. And there you sit with one less customer, one more bad word-of-mouth, and perhaps an angry boss.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I came up with this little function, it checks you use the format `DD(separator)MM(sameseparator)YYYY`

With DD, MM and YYYY as integers.

```
function valid_date($input_date) {
    if(!preg_match('/(?P<d>\d{2})(?P<sep>\D)(?P<m>\d{2})\2(?P<y>\d{4})/',$input_date, $aux_date)) 
        return false; 
    $aux = mktime(0,0,0,$aux_date['m'],$aux_date['d'],$aux_date['y']);
    return $input_date == date('d'.$aux_date['sep'].'m'.$aux_date['sep'].'Y',$aux);
}
```

(Edited as sugested below)

Comment: Why not just `return $input_date == date('d'.$aux_date['sep'].'m'.$aux_date['sep'].'Y',$aux)`.  You have 3 lines of uselessness otherwise. +1 for the regex though: I didn't know you can name your groups.

Answer (score 13):

```
$date = str_replace("/", "-", $incoming);
$d = explode("-"  , $date);
```

Re-assemble the parts and then run it through checkdate

```
if( !checkdate($d[1], $d[0], $d[2]) )
echo 'Not a recognised date' ;
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php

Comment: +1 This is the right way to validate a date, not `strtotime()`

Comment: I did not know there was a checkdate function... Life is now easier.

Comment: added the count check for $d as it was throwing exception  for the following test case       @zerkms this will take care of your input       '27/09-2010';

if( count($d)!=3 || !checkdate($d[1], $d[0], $d[2]) )
echo 'Not a recognised date' ;`

Answer (score 1):

A very simplistic way would be to have a regular expression that checks for one of the formats, then make sure the input is converted to that first by replacing any characters:

```
$regexDate = '#\d\d\-\d\d\-\d\d\d\d#' ;

$dateIn = trim($_GET['date']) ;

//replace all / with - since our regex expects those
$dateIn = str_replace('/', '-', $dateIn) ;

if (preg_match($regexDate, $dateIn)) {
    //valid date input
}
```

Comment: This doesn't check if the date is *valid*.

Comment: @Dan, hence "simplistic". You can pair it up with checking if the date elements are within ranges later but you have to start somewhere

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend using the PHP method`strtotime()`, as it will not only check to see if the *format* is valid, but if the time specified by the format is correct as well (i.e. there will never be a February 31st, but a regex might not catch this).

You can check to see if this is valid with `if (strtotime($toCheck)) {` as it'll return `FALSE` if it doesn't succeed (http://us2.php.net/strtotime).

**EDIT:**
You'll need to switch the order before you can check if the date is valid with `strtotime` first like this:

```
$str = "07-31-1987";
$str = preg_replace('/([^-\/]+)[-\/]([^-\/]+)[-\/]([^-\/]+)/', '$2-$1-$3', $str);
echo date('r', strtotime($str)) . "\n"; // Fri, 31 Jul 1987 00:00:00 -0700
```

Comment: `strtotime()` doesn't handle dd/MM/YYY

Comment: `echo date('r', strtotime('07/31/2010'))); // Sat, 31 Jul 2010 00:00:00 -0700`

Comment: You would need to convert the date string into mm/dd/yyyy or mm-dd-yyyy before calling strtotime().

Comment: +1 for strtotime but make sure to either set it in stone to your users to use US date format, or try to do it for them as a fallback

Comment: @w3d - just did, but I think better overall approach it to split `<input>`s into day, month, year (so you'll have better control...)

Comment: -1 This answer is all wrong. (1) `strtotime()` doesn't support `mm-dd-YYYY`, only `mm/dd/YYYY` (2) `strtotime()` doesn't validate the date. `strtotime('Feb 31st 2010')` for example does not return false. Cups' answer is the right one. And wow, is that an ugly regex or what? Ironic that you donwvoted everyone, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use strftime and strptime. At first I'd convert string into "time" than back to string and compare it...

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [datetime](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) class, passing the date you want to validate to the constructor. If you have a valid date you'll get back a datetime object. If it's an invalid date the constructor will throw an exception, which you can catch and the handle the error accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
'/^(?=\d)(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:0?[13578]|1[02])(\/|-|\.)31)\1|(?:(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])(\/|-|\.)(?:29|30)\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})|(?:0?2(\/|-|\.)29\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))|(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2}))($|\ (?=\d)))?(((0?[1-9]|1[012])(:[0-5]\d){0,2}(\ [AP]M))|([01]\d|2[0-3])(:[0-5]\d){1,2})?$/'
```

This will Do the business.

Answer (score -1):

A regular expression alone cannot validate a date because of the different number of days in months - especially for leap years.

```
/^(\d{1,2})(\/|-)(\d{1,2})\2(\d{2}|\d{4})$/
```

but above regex solves your problem of allowing - or / based on these format dd-mm-yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy

Here are some examples

```
//Date d/m/yy and dd/mm/yyyy
//1/1/00 through 31/12/99 and 01/01/1900 through 31/12/2099
//Matches invalid dates such as February 31st
'\b(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0?[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)?[0-9]{2}\b'

//Date dd/mm/yyyy
//01/01/1900 through 31/12/2099
//Matches invalid dates such as February 31st
'(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)[0-9]{2}'

//Date m/d/y and mm/dd/yyyy
//1/1/99 through 12/31/99 and 01/01/1900 through 12/31/2099
//Matches invalid dates such as February 31st
//Accepts dashes, spaces, forward slashes and dots as date separators
'\b(0?[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)?[0-9]{2}\b'

//Date mm/dd/yyyy
//01/01/1900 through 12/31/2099
//Matches invalid dates such as February 31st
'(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)[0-9]{2}'

//Date yy-m-d or yyyy-mm-dd
//00-1-1 through 99-12-31 and 1900-01-01 through 2099-12-31
//Matches invalid dates such as February 31st
'\b(19|20)?[0-9]{2}[- /.](0?[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\b'

//Date yyyy-mm-dd
//1900-01-01 through 2099-12-31
//Matches invalid dates such as February 31st
'(19|20)[0-9]{2}[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])'
```

- http://www.roscripts.com/PHP_regular_expressions_examples-136.html

Comment: This would also allow `5/2/02`, i.e. it does not meet the requirements. At least you should mention it.

Comment: This doesn't check if the date is *valid*.